# Math Constraint Problems

Tags: linear-programming, systems-of-equations

This is a homework problem of mine.  The professor said we can use any resource to help us solve and I cannot get up with anyone from class.  Please help.  I'm not looking for a direct answer, I really need someone to help me solve this step by step.

You own two liquor distribution sites in two different locations.  You receive orders from two customers. Customer A needs 50 gallons. Customer B needs 70 gallons.  Your East side store has 80 gallons.  Your West side store has 45 gallons.  Delivery cost per gallon are:
from east store 0.50 for A, 0.60 for B and from your west store 0.40 for A and 0.55 for B.

How do you arrange your shipping to minimize your cost

P.s. Sorry, I corrected it The east store has 80 gallons not 45.

Comment: Both stores together have $45+45=90$ gallons. And the customers need $50+70=120$. So you cannot satisfy the needs of both customers. Does this question actually ask us how to ship all the gallons the stores have to minimize the cost without having to satisfy every need of the customers?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$cost = \frac4{10}n_w + \frac12 n_e +\frac{55}{100}p_w +\frac6{10}p_e $$

$ $

$
$n_w$ is the number of gallons sent from the west store to A

$n_e$ is the number of gallons sent from the east store to A

$p_w$ is the number of gallons sent from the west store to B

$p_e$ is the number of gallons sent from the east store to B

$$
$$
observe that:$$ \frac4{10}\lt \frac12 \lt \frac{55}{100}\lt \frac6{10} $$

How can you "distribute" the number of gallons so that the cost is minimized?